# Granting permission to SQL database

Tags: sql-server, permissions

How do you grant a user xp_cmdshell, sp_OACreate, sp_OAmethod, and sp_Destroy on SQL server 2008? What is the prons and cons of granting this permission? Please let me know. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

All those 4 procedures require the sysadmin fixed server role or CONTROL SERVER permission. What are the pros and cons of granting this level of permission to a user that's not a DBA? This is like opening Pandora's box :-).

Answer (score 2):

Instead you should consider using SQLCLR as some of the ones you listed are notorious for memory issues + security issues as well.

Note that you can also shoot yourself in the foot with SQLCLR but I am NOT qualified to speak abt it.

Comment: Agree. sp_OA% have so many issues...